# Matcher be_true ruby/rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Estou começando a estudar sobre ruby/rspec seguindo um livro, mas não estou conseguindo progredir utilizando o `matcher be_true`.

Segue abaixo o erro:

```
BagOfWords#push is possible to put words on it (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

1) BagOfWords#push is possible to put words on it
  Failure/Error: expect(isTrue).to be_true
    expected true to respond to `true?`
  # ./spec/bag_of_words_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (require d)>'

Finished in 0.015 seconds (files took 0.54403 seconds to load)  
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/bag_of_words_spec.rb:7 # BagOfWords#push is possible to put words on it
```

Comment: Qual versão do RSpec você está usando? Você pode tentar usar o `be_truthy` se for RSpec 3.

Comment: Desculpa a demora em responder... Era isso mesmo, estou usando do RSpec 3, só  troquei e funcionou valeu.

Comment: @cido18, pode incluir a resposta ao problema e aceitá-la? Isso evita perguntas que já estão respondidas nos comentários continuem sendo listadas como "Sem resposta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com essa [thread](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283), os matchers `be_true` e `be_false` foram substituídos por `be_truthy` and `be_falsey`. Você ainda pode utilizar o `be true` e `be false` (note que são separados).

A diferença entre `be true` e `be_truthy` é que um teste utilizando o `be_truthy` irá passar caso o objeto não seja `nil`. O inverso acontece para o `be false` e `be_falsey`.

Da [documentação oficial](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers), temos:

```
expect(objeto).to be_truthy   # passa se o objeto não for nil ou false
expect(objeto).to be true     # passa somente se o objeto for true
expect(objeto).to be_falsy    # passa se o objeto for nil ou false
expect(objeto).to be false    # passa somente se o objeto for false
```

#### Exemplos

```
it { expect(true).to be true }        # passa
it { expect("string").to be true }    # falha
it { expect(nil).to be true }         # falha
it { expect(false).to be true }       # falha

it { expect(false).to be false }      # passa
it { expect("string").to be false}    # falha
it { expect(nil).to be false}         # falha
it { expect(true).to be false}        # falha
```

Answer (score 0):

Resposta:
Qual versão do RSpec você está usando? Você pode tentar usar o be_truthy se for RSpec 3. – @Bruno dos Santos